# Is this code over releasing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, release

I can´t find where the problem is, but this code is crashing. Am I over releasing any object?

```
settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsController" bundle:nil];
settings.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

NSArray * arrayWithRootController = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:settings, nil];
[(UINavigationController*)([self.tabBar.viewControllers lastObject])setViewControllers:arrayWithRootController];
[arrayWithRootController release];
[settings release];
```

If I remove the line

```
[settings release];
```

The app doesn´t crash. but I am pretty sure its correct. May the problem be in another place?

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post details of the crash? The error would be very useful.

Comment: @user1394965 You are wrong! iOS6 doesn't change anything in memory management. I believe you've mixed it up with Automatic Reference Counting. (Which btw. is available in iOS4/5 too!)

Comment: If UINavigationController retains its view controllers, this code looks correct. You can simplify things a little by using the NSArray factory method `-arrayWithObject:` because the result is autoreleasing.

Comment: viewControllers is a property defined as copy according to Apple

Comment: Is there a good reason to torture yourself or are you just trying to understand pre-ARC era?

Comment: I am guessing you accidentally release self inside SettingsViewController. But that's just an idea, because I don't know the code. At least in the part of code you posted I can't find any mistake.

Comment: Do you use `settings` anywhere else in your code? Have you made sure that `self.tabBar.viewControllers` is non-nil? Not sure why that would cause a crash, but it would cause your VC to be released.

Comment: Theres the obly place where I use the "settings" object. Maybe the problem is in the dealloc settings code

Answer (score 1):

You're not overreleasing in this snippet, but obviously something isn't right. Adding the root view controller to the array will retain it, but only for the life of the array. When the array dies, all the objects within it are released as well (my guess as to what's happening here).

Couple things to try:
First, make sure you're putting your array where you think you are:

```
[(UINavigationController*)([self.tabBar.viewControllers lastObject])setViewControllers:arrayWithRootController];
```

What do you expect `[self.tabBar.viewControllers lastObject]` to be? Are you sure this is where you want to be assigning your new array? If the receiver is invalid, your array won't be retained in your next line which means the view controller will also be released.

I'm not familiar with your architecture, but it appears you're assigning an array of view controllers to a view controller. `self.tabBar` is a navigation controller, and you can call `setViewControllers` on it. But `self.tabBar.viewControllers lastObject`... well presumably that's a view controller, but not neccessarily a navigation controller, it may not respond to setViewControllers (in which case it should crash, unless it's nil, which I'm guessing it might be).

Finally, try using the Instruments tool Zombies to see if you can pinpoint where the unintended release is coming from.

Comment: Yes, Im putting the array in the correct place, I tried adding another view controller instead of "settings" and its not crashing. The problem is 100% sure in the settings object

Comment: [UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] thats the method where the ref count of the object reaches -1

Comment: It looks like you created some of your interface in a XIB. Do you have a UITableViewController object in there somewhere? Is the associated property definitely strong/retained?